# Why is runtime of Fibonacci θ(1.6^N)?

Tags: runtime, big-o, fibonacci

Why is the runtime closer to O(1.6^N) and not O(2^N)? I think it has something to do with the call stack, but it's still a little unclear to me.

```
int Fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    else
        return Fibonacci(n - 1) + Fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: where did you get the idea of it is O(1.6^N)?

Comment: The precise expression is `O(ϕ^N)` where `ϕ = ½(1+√5) ≈ 1.618...` is the Golden Ratio. You can obtain this by making a substitution `T(N) = a^N` into the recurrence relation `T(N) = T(N - 1) + T(N - 2) + O(1)` and solving for the base `a`. See [this page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-recursive-fibonacci-program/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The number φ = (1+sqrt(5))/2 is characterized by the two following properties:

1. φ >= 1
2. φ<sup>2</sup> = φ + 1.

Multiplying the second equation by φ<sup>{n-1}</sup> we get

3. φ<sup>n+1</sup> = φ<sup>n</sup> + φ<sup>n-1</sup>

Since f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1 and f(n+1) = f(n) + f(n-1), using **1** and **3**,

it is easy to see by induction in n that f(n) <= φ<sup>n</sup>

Thus f(n) is O(φ<sup>n</sup>).

A similar inductive argument shows that

f(n) >= φ<sup>n-3</sup> = φ<sup>-3</sup>φ<sup>n</sup>      (n >= 1)

thus f(n) = Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

For starters, remember that big-O notation always provides an upper bound. That is, if a function is O(n), it's also O(n<sup>2</sup>), O(n<sup>3</sup>), O(2<sup>n</sup>), etc. So in that sense, you are not incorrect if you say that the runtime is O(2<sup>n</sup>). You just don't have a tight bound.

To see where the tight bound of Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>) comes from, it might help to look at how many recursive calls end up getting made when evaluating `Fibonacci(n)`. Notice that

- `Fibonacci(0)` requires one call, the call to `Fibonacci(0)`.
- `Fibonacci(1)` requires one call, the call to `Fibonacci(1)`.
- `Fibonacci(2)` requires three calls: one to `Fibonacci(2)`, and one each to `Fibonacci(0)` and `Fibonacci(1)`.
- `Fibonacci(3)` requires five calls: one to `Fibonacci(3)`, then the three calls generated by invoking `Fibonacci(2)` and the one call generated by invoking `Fibonacci(1)`.
- `Fibonacci(4)` requires nine calls: one to `Fibonacci(4)`, then five from the call to `Fibonacci(3)` and three from the call to `Fibonacci(2)`.

More generally, the pattern seems to be that if you're calling `Fibonacci(n)` for some n ≥ 2, that the number of calls made is one (for the call itself), plus the number of calls needed to evaluate `Fibonacci(n-1)` and `Fibonacci(n-2)`. If we let L<sub>n</sub> denote the number of calls made, this means that we have that

- L<sub>0</sub> = L<sub>1</sub> = 1
- L<sub>n+2</sub> = 1 + L<sub>n</sub> + L<sub>n+1</sub>.

So now the question is how fast this sequence grows. Evaluating the first few terms gives us

> 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 25, 41, ...

which definitely gets bigger and bigger, but it's not clear how much bigger that is.

Something you might notice here is that L<sub>n</sub> kinda sorta ish looks like the Fibonacci numbers. That is, it's defined in terms of the sum of the two previous terms, but it has an extra +1 term. So maybe we might want to look at the difference between L<sub>n</sub> and F<sub>n</sub>, since that might show us how much "faster" the L series grows. You might notice that the first two values of the L series are 1, 1 and the first two values of the Fibonacci series are 0, 1, so we'll shift things over by one term to make things line up a bit more nicely:

```
L(n)     1   1   3   5   9  15  25  41
F(n+1)   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21
Diff:    0   0   1   2   4   7  12  20
```

And wait, hold on a second. What happens if we add one to each term of the difference? That gives us

```
L(n)     1   1   3   5   9  15  25  41
F(n+1)   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21
Diff+1   1   1   2   3   5   8  13  21
```

Whoa! Looks like L<sub>n</sub> - F<sub>n+1</sub> + 1 = F<sub>n+1</sub>. Rearranging, we see that

> L<sub>n</sub> = 2F<sub>n+1</sub> - 1.

Wow! So the actual number of calls made by the Fibonacci recursive function is very closely related to the actual value returned. So we could say that the runtime of the Fibonacci function is Θ(F<sub>n+1</sub>) and we'd be correct.

But now the question is where φ comes in. There's a lovely mathematical result called [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet's_formula) that says that F<sub>n</sub> = Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>). There are many ways to prove this, but they all essentially boil down to the observation that

1. the Fibonacci numbers seem to grow exponentially quickly;
2. if they grow exponentially with a base of x, then F<sub>n+2</sub> = F<sub>n</sub> + F<sub>n+1</sub> can be rewritten as x<sup>2</sup> = x + 1; and
3. φ is a solution to x<sup>2</sup> = x + 1.

From this, we can see that since the runtime of Fibonacci is Θ(F<sub>n+1</sub>), then the runtime is also Θ(φ<sup>n+1</sup>) = Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>).